# How to configure yii2 with phpstorm

Tags: yii2

I have found some ways to config Yii 1 with phpstorm. But I don't know how to deal with Yii 2.

When use phpstorm, there are some errors. such as `Yii::$app->db2`, This method will cause

> "Field access via magic method",

and some method `bindValue,queryOne` will also cause some problems.

Answer (score 1):

There is, at this point, no native functionality for `Yii2` as a framework (It's just `Yii1` and `Symfony` if I recall correctly).

That being said: `Yii2`'s source code is filled  with `DocBlock`'s (and the needed `@var` and `@property` statements. So the editor is able to make out a lot on its own now even without native support. 
For that reason I don't think they will be implementing support for it anytime soon.